# Kendo UI - Store image path in database through upload widget in grid

Tags: c#, javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-upload

I'm able to upload images and save them to a folder, but the only issue is storing the path in an SQL table. I want to save the Photo path to the database so that it can be displayed elsewhere. This is what I have so far.

Item class:

```
public class Item
{
    public int ItemId { get; set; }
    public string ItemName { get; set; }
    public string Photo { get; set; }
}
```

Here's the Update action of the controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Update(item, HttpPostedFileBase files)
{
    if (files != null && files.ContentLength > 0)
        {
            string fileName = Path.GetFileName(files.FileName);
            var physicalPath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Content/uploads"), fileName);

            item.Photo = physicalPath;
            files.SaveAs(physicalPath);

            return Json(new { Photo = fileName }, "text/plain");
        }

    return Json(new[] { item });
}
```

Grid sample with upload widget integration:
http://jsbin.com/safog/1

Answer (score 0):

try with below code its working fine.

```
           [HttpPost]
           public ActionResult Update(item, HttpPostedFileBase files)
            {
             if (files != null && files.ContentLength > 0)
               {
                string fileName = Path.GetFileName(files.FileName);
                 var physicalPath = path.Combine(HttpContext.Request.MapPath("~/Content/uploads"), fileName);
                 item.Photo = physicalPath;
                 files.SaveAs(physicalPath);
                 return Json(new { Photo = fileName }, "text/plain");
              } 
         return Json(new[] { item });
           }
```

Comment: The problem is I didn't get any error at all. But when I check the database, nothing gets updated.

Comment: Have write any code for insert file path into database ?